# typedef usage in struct definition

Tags: c++, header, typedef

I have problem with this code,this is a header file(stack.h) from a maze program. i was studying Stack structure, and in my documents, i couldn't understand these type of structures, can anyone explain to me why we are using typedef and how the 12th and 21st line works??

```
    #ifndef STACK_H
    #define STACK_H 
    #define STACKSIZE 50 

    typedef struct d {
        int x;
        int y;
        int right; int left;
        int down;
        int up;
        int camefrom;
        ￼} StackDataType, position;           /// LINE 12

    struct STACK{
        StackDataType element[STACKSIZE]; int top;
        void create();
        void close();
        bool push(StackDataType); StackDataType pop();
        bool isempty();
    };
    typedef struct STACK Stack;             /// LINE 21
    #endif
```

Comment: First link after [googling typedef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef)

Comment: Cannot count up to line 21, but line 12 (` StackDataType, position;`) provides typedef instances for the struct which isn't correct c++ syntax.

Comment: There's no good reason to use typedef here. This code is written very oddly. It looks like C code that has been partially ported to C++. I wouldn't spend too much time learning from it. Good C++ code doesn't look like that.

Comment: If these are your lecture notes, you need to afraid. Your lecturer is a C programmer who has fumbled their way into C++ and is about to make you into a terrible C++ programmer. You should consider complaining to the faculty. I really hope they don't have tenure. Especially taht first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not need to typedef a struct again in C++, it again defines a struct, which is unnecessary. You can just define:

```
struct d{

};
```

Answer (score 1):

In my (considerable) experience, this almost always denotes a C programmer who has fumbled their way into C++. If these are notes from your classes, it doesn't bode well.

In the earliest "C", if you declared a `struct`

```
struct StructName {
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

This didn't declare a type name, it only declared a struct name, so to make an instance of StructName you would have to write:

```
struct StructName myStruct;
```

If you wanted to be able to omit the "StructName" part you would need to use a typedef:

```
struct StructName { int a, b; };
typedef struct StructName StructName;
```

Or you could combine these into one, somewhat confusing, statement:

```
typedef struct StructName { int a, b; } StructName;
```

I say confusing because if the `struct` definition is many lines long, it could be confused for a second C syntax which lets you declare an instance of a Struct after defining the type:

```
struct StructName { int a, b; } StructName;
// aka
struct StructName { int a, b; };
struct StructName StructName; // local variable, StructName of type struct StructName
// declare a VARIABLE called StructName which is of type anonymous-struct.
struct { int a, b; } StructName;
```

One problem with this is that you can't use the typedef'd name in the structure declaration:

```
// Won't compile because 'List' isn't declared until the end.
typedef struct list_structure { List* next; int a; } List;

// Won't compile because you have to remember to say 'struct List'
typedef struct List { List* next; int a; } List;

// Compiles
typedef struct list_structure { struct list_structure* next; int a; } List;
```

This confused a lot of C programmers. Enough so that many C programmers will tell you that the definition of a struct is

```
typedef struct tag_name { /* struct details */ } structname;
//e.g.
typedef struct tagStructName { int a, b; } StructName;
```

C++ inherited all of this, but also went ahead and made the typedef implied for you:

```
// doesn't compile as C, will compile as C++
struct List {
    List* next;
    int a;
};
```

To see it not compiling as C: http://ideone.com/3r9TRy

In C++, declaring something as a class is *exactly* the same as declaring it a struct, with one change:

```
class List {
    List* next;
public:
    int a;
};
```

Is *EXACTLY* as though you had written:

```
struct List {
private:
    List* next;
public:
    int a;
};
```

There's no other difference between a `struct` and a `class` in C++.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two problems: The first is the mysterious symbol `￼` in the definition of the `d` structure. The second is that you use `typedef` for that structure too, but have something after the typename `StackDataType`. The second error you get is probably just because of the first one, it's very common in C and C++ to get errors in unrelated lines because of previous errors.

Besides, in C++ you don't really need `typedef` for structures, as they are the same as classes so doing e.g. `struct StackDataType {...};` will allow you to use `StackDataType` as a type.

Comment: Which mysterious symbol you mean? I couldn't see it. Thanks for answer.

Comment: @fucicek There's a non-ASCII character between the last newline (after the `camefrom` declaration) and the closing brace. Look at the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

What's going on is that essentially the `typedef` is being used to create a shorthand way to refer to the given structure.

So in this example, both `StackDataType` and `position` are shorthand references to what is formally declared as `struct d`, and `Stack` is a shorthand reference to what is formally declared as `struct STACK`.

Generally speaking, this allows for cleaner code referencing these structures. E.g., instead of having to write:

```
struct STACK var;
```

to declare an instance of this structure, you can just use:

```
Stack var;
```

You can declare a typedef either at the same point at which you declare the type (as in the first example), or you can declare it later (as in the second).